# Effect of NOLOCK hint in SELECT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

I guess the real question is:

If I don't care about dirty reads, will adding the **with (NOLOCK)** hint to a SELECT statement affect the performance of:

1. the current SELECT statement
2. other transactions against the given table

Example:

```
Select * 
from aTable with (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: These [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12610346/641833) and [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50029/9210) answers are a little clearer as to what is actually happening.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

1) **Yes**, a select with `NOLOCK` will complete faster than a normal select.

2) **Yes**, a select with `NOLOCK` will allow other queries against the effected table to complete faster than a normal select.

**Why would this be?**

`NOLOCK` typically (depending on your DB engine) means give me your data, and I don't care what state it is in, and don't bother holding it still while you read from it. It is all at once faster, less resource-intensive, and very very dangerous.

You should be warned to never do an update from or perform anything system critical, or where absolute correctness is required using data that originated from a `NOLOCK` read. It is absolutely possible that this data contains rows that were deleted during the query's run or that have been deleted in other sessions that have yet to be finalized. It is possible that this data includes rows that have been partially updated. It is possible that this data contains records that violate foreign key constraints. It is possible that this data excludes rows that have been added to the table but have yet to be committed.

*You really have no way to know what the state of the data is.*

If you're trying to get things like a Row Count or other summary data where some margin of error is acceptable, then `NOLOCK` is a good way to boost performance for these queries and avoid having them negatively impact database performance.

**Always use the `NOLOCK` hint with great caution and treat any data it returns suspiciously.**

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I've been assuming but was questioned about it by a colleague and my initial research made me question myself.  SQLServer 2005 documentation says that with NOLOCK is the default locking scheme for all select statements!  I'd guess then that my hints would be redundant in ...

Comment: ... 2005 and not have any effect.  We're running 2000 right now (thanks to our vendor) and there no similar statement in the documentation.

Comment: Your friend needs to read the documentation.

Table Hint (Transact-SQL)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Side note: if this was true, it would be absolute chaos.

Comment: Points 1 and 2 need to be restricted to 1) "... _when an insert/update/delete action is pending on the table_." and  2) "... will allow _insert/update/delete_ queries against ...".  I would (personal preference) change instances of "faster" to "sooner" since the difference is waiting for another process complete.

Answer (score 65):

NOLOCK makes most SELECT statements faster, because of the lack of shared locks. Also, the lack of issuance of the locks means that writers will not be impeded by your SELECT.

NOLOCK is functionally equivalent to an isolation level of READ UNCOMMITTED. The main difference is that you can use NOLOCK on some tables but not others, if you choose. If you plan to use NOLOCK on all tables in a complex query, then using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED is easier, because you don't have to apply the hint to every table.

Here is information about all of the isolation levels at your disposal, as well as table hints.

[SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763(SQL.90).aspx)

[Table Hint (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: I agree, but not completely; it is important to point out that a NO LOCK / READ UNCOMMITTED hint doesn't actually improve the speed of the query, but more-so makes it appear faster because it doesn't have to wait for previous queries to complete. So really, the query SEEMS faster, rather than IS faster (I think).

Comment: @BorhanMooz Well, there is the savings from not having to request locks from the lock manager. Even if there are no other queries waiting, this has a cost and a memory overhead.

Comment: I was discussing this with some of my work-mates. As I understand it, a query using a WITH(NOLOCK) hint still requires a Schema-Shared lock to be attained (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/).

Comment: Yes, but not thousands of shared locks on pages or extents. A Schema lock is ONE lock, not THOUSANDS. If we want to be pedantic, we can continue to debate this, but yes, there will be a minimal amount of lock overhead. The savings are significant. Do the math on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337559(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 14):

In addition to what is said above, you should be very aware that nolock actually imposes the risk of you **not** getting rows that has been committed **before** your select.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx

Answer (score 7):

It will be faster because it doesnt have to wait for locks

Comment: How much faster? Could you provide any speed improvements numbers?

Comment: "How much" depends on what you are specifically doing with your data and how long you typically have to wait for a lock acquisition.

Comment: The only correct benchmark is the one you create & run yourself.  What everybody tells you is as good as "the check is in the mail".  I've proven many myths and assumptions wrong many times by running my own benchmarks.

Comment: ^ @TravisO - is completely correct. I've had NOLOCK execute slower a few times. Not entirely sure why, but I'm using that when troubleshooting and I dont want to negatively (over)affect production

Answer (score 2):

- The answer is **Yes** if the query is run multiple times at once, because each transaction won't need to wait for the others to complete. However, If the query is run once on its own then the answer is No.
- **Yes**. There's a significant probability that careful use of WITH(NOLOCK) will speed up your database overall. It means that other transactions won't have to wait for this SELECT statement to finish, but on the other hand, other transactions will slow down as they're now sharing their processing time with a new transaction.

Be careful to **only** use `WITH (NOLOCK)` in SELECT statements on tables that have a clustered index.

WITH(NOLOCK) is often exploited as a magic way to speed up database read transactions.

The result set can contain rows that have not yet been committed, that are often later rolled back.

If WITH(NOLOCK) is applied to a table that has a non-clustered index then row-indexes can be changed by other transactions as the row data is being streamed into the result-table. This means that the result-set can be missing rows or display the same row multiple times.

READ COMMITTED adds an additional issue where data is corrupted within a single column where multiple users change the same cell simultaneously.