# Understanding SQL Server LOCKS on SELECT queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I'm wondering what is the benefit to use `SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)` on a table if the only other queries affecting that table are `SELECT` queries.

How is that handled by SQL Server? Would a `SELECT` query block another `SELECT` query?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and a Linq-to-SQL `DataContext`.

(EDIT)

About performance :

- Would a 2nd `SELECT` have to wait for a 1st `SELECT` to finish if using a locked `SELECT`?
- Versus a `SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)`?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

A `SELECT` in SQL Server will place a *shared lock* on a table row - and a second `SELECT` would also require a shared lock, and those are compatible with one another.

So no - one `SELECT` cannot block another `SELECT`.

What the `WITH (NOLOCK)` query hint is used for is to be able to read data that's in the process of being inserted (by another connection) and that hasn't been committed yet.

Without that query hint, a `SELECT` might be blocked reading a table by an ongoing `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`) statement that places an *exclusive* lock on rows (or possibly a whole table), until that operation's transaction has been committed (or rolled back).

Problem of the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint is: you might be reading data rows that aren't going to be inserted at all, in the end (if the `INSERT` transaction is rolled back) - so your e.g. report might show data that's never really been committed to the database.

There's another query hint that might be useful - `WITH (READPAST)`. This instructs the `SELECT` command to just skip any rows that it attempts to read and that are locked exclusively. The `SELECT` will not block, and it will not read any "dirty" un-committed data - but it might skip some rows, e.g. not show all your rows in the table.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks a lot! Would there be an impact (on hundreds of `SELECT` queries) to use `WITH (NOLOCK)` without reason?

Comment: We use with nolock in 99.5% of our selects, no joke.  If an admin is updating a user record you don't want that to cause the report to sit there and wait for the whole distributed transaction to finish.  So their old data shows up on the report.  Who cares?  If the report had been run a second before that's the same data that would have been there with rowlock.  The only place it's a concern is data that isn't committed yet.  If you're showing "orders in the last hour" that could potentially be an issue, but a tiny, tiny issue compared to speed/concurrency gains.

Comment: Also since 'report' was thrown out as an example, reports are typically for a time period that is not the past 5 minutes.  Reporting on data from last month with nolock - well it's not like the data is going to rollback a month later.

Comment: @FrancisP: other than potentially having "dirty" data in your result set - no, I don't see any (negative) impact. And as Brian White correctly stated - if you're doing reporting etc., it's rather unlikely you'll get unwanted, non-committed data

Comment: Oh and guys, If I got a table where each user is accessing its own rows (according to user_id), and they're doing `SELECT`,`INSERT` and `DELETE` operations, would an `INSERT` query block the entire table? (Since the other requests are `INSERT` or `SELECT` queries affecting different rows..)

Comment: @FrancisP: not if you insert a small number of rows - in that case, it just locks the new rows being inserted. If you insert more than roughly 5000 rows at once - then a lock escalation will occur and the whole table will be exclusively locked.

Comment: @marc_s : No, only inserting or deleting 1 row per query and mostly selecting 1 row per query on that table. But I also have some other tables accessed by all users for `SELECT` queries using same Data and was wondering if a `WITH (NOLOCK)` was realy relevant for that situation.

Comment: we put WITH (NOLOCK) just the beginning of the query?

Comment: Very nice answer..It felt like an all in one tutorial for SQL locks!! glad I got in here!

Answer (score 39):

On performance you keep focusing on select.
Shared does not block reads.
Shared lock  blocks update.
If you have hundreds of shared locks it is going to take an update a while to get an exclusive lock as it must wait for shared locks to clear.

By default a select (read) takes a shared lock.
Shared (S) locks allow concurrent transactions to read (SELECT) a resource.
A shared lock as no effect on other selects (1 or a 1000).

The difference is how the nolock versus shared lock effects update or insert operation.

No other transactions can modify the data while shared (S) locks exist on the resource.

A shared lock blocks an update!
But nolock does not block an update.

This can have huge impacts on performance of updates.  It also impact inserts.

Dirty read (nolock) just sounds dirty.  You are never going to get partial data.   If an update is changing John to Sally you are never going to get Jolly.

I use shared locks a lot for concurrency.  Data is stale as soon as it is read.  A read of John that changes to Sally the next millisecond is stale data.  A read of Sally that gets rolled back John the next millisecond is stale data.   That is on the millisecond level.  I have a dataloader that take 20 hours to run if users are taking shared locks and 4 hours to run is users are taking no lock.  Shared locks in this case cause data to be 16 hours stale.

Don't use nolocks wrong.  But they do have a place.  If you are going to cut a check when a byte is set to 1 and then set it to 2 when the check is cut - not a time for a nolock.

Comment: Thank you.  We see similar performance characteristics.  Our site wouldn't run if we required locks for reads, and the impact of not having it in most cases is just insignificant.

Comment: @BrianWhite Thank you. Someone gets it.  And I take a lot of table locks on update and insert.  Get in, get it done, and get out is my approach.

Comment: Dirty read (nolock) just sounds dirty. You are never going to get partial data. If an update is changing John to Sally you are never going to get Jolly. - we read John right?

Comment: Updates in sql server use update lock (U) that is later converted to exclusive lock (X). (see http://www.madeiradata.com/role-update-lock-sql-server/) Update lock doesn't block shared locks, but exclusive lock blocks all other locks (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @kolobok going to take an update a while to get an exclusive lock

Answer (score 18):

I have to add one important comment. Everyone is mentioning that `NOLOCK`reads only dirty data. This is not precise. It is also possible that you'll get the same row twice or the whole row is skipped during your read. The reason is that you could ask for some data at the same time when SQL Server is re-balancing b-tree.

Check another threads

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5469238/2108874

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/quaere-verum-clustered-index-scans-part-iii.aspx)

> With the NOLOCK hint (or setting the isolation level of the session to READ UNCOMMITTED) you tell SQL Server that you don't expect consistency, so there are no guarantees. Bear in mind though that "inconsistent data" does not only mean that you might see uncommitted changes that were later rolled back, or data changes in an intermediate state of the transaction. **It also means that in a simple query that scans all table/index data SQL Server may lose the scan position, or you might end up getting the same row twice.**

Answer (score 11):

At my work, we have a very big system that runs on many PCs at the same time, with very big tables with hundreds of thousands of rows, and sometimes many millions of rows.

When you make a SELECT on a very big table, let's say you want to know every transaction a user has made in the past 10 years, and the primary key of the table is not built in an efficient way, the query might take several minutes to run.

Then, our application might me running on many user's PCs at the same time, accessing the same database. So if someone tries to insert into the table that the other SELECT is reading (in pages that SQL is trying to read), then a LOCK can occur and the two transactions block each other.

We had to add a "NO LOCK" to our SELECT statement, because it was a huge SELECT on a table that is used a lot by a lot of users at the same time and we had LOCKS all the time.

I don't know if my example is clear enough? This is a real life example.

Comment: Thank you for the example, but I'm only wondering about SELECT queries affecting other SELECT queries (on that same table)..

Comment: They won't, but a select statement could be part of transaction that includes an update.  Update tbl set x = (select max(y) from tbl) where z = (select min(a) from tbl).  If you have a concurrent select z from tbl well the other selects aren't blocking it, but the update is.

Comment: I had exactly this issue that a long running select was blocking my inserts

Comment: The transactions won't block each other - the select will block the update.  Here's a couple of interesting links that have just helped me understand a little more about how this stuff works: [first one](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/15/sql-server-concurrency-basics-guest-post-by-vinod-kumar/) [second one](http://blogs.extremeexperts.com/2012/11/15/sql-server-locking-basics/)

Comment: @JonnyLeeds : Your 2nd link doesn't work anymore. Here is an archived link of [SQL Server: Locking basics](http://web.archive.org/web/20170930025858/http://blogs.extremeexperts.com:80/2012/11/15/sql-server-locking-basics)

Answer (score 3):

The `SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)` allows reads  of uncommitted data, which is equivalent to having the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level set on your database. The `NOLOCK` keyword allows finer grained control than setting the isolation level on the entire database.

Wikipedia has a useful article: [Wikipedia: Isolation (database systems)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems))

It is also discussed at length in other stackoverflow articles.

Comment: Thanks rghome for the additional information you provided.

Comment: This is why I prefer using the `READUNCOMMITTED` (an alias for `NOLOCK`) hint, *when* such is a valid use-case. Doing so makes the actual operation, which *isn't* really "without locks", less unclear.

Answer (score 1):

select with no lock - will select records which may / may not going to be inserted. you will read a dirty data.

for example - lets say a transaction insert 1000 rows and then fails.

when you select - you will get the 1000 rows.

Comment: But what if no record is intended to be inserted in that table, is the NO LOCK still relevant?

Comment: no it is not. since read uses a shared lock which can be acquired by more than 1 sessions. there is no way of getting dirty data.

Comment: I rather not to answer on a thing I'm not sure of. :-)