# Select Statement Is Causing Insert statement to block

Tags: sql-server, locking

How Intended shared lock can impact inserts

Hi All,

i have gone through some blogs and find out that the Select statement (shared lock) can also block 
the insert and update statement. i understand that this is true and i am try to replicate this.
but somehow i am not able to replicate this. can anyone please help me to replicate this issue

This is what i am trying to do

Connection 1

```
BEGIN TRAN 
Select * from myBigTable 
COMMIT
```

Connection 2

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRAN 
        INSERT INTO MyBigTable(.....)
        SELECT ......
    COMMIT 
END
```

But both are running fine. can someone guide me on replicating this issue.

Thanks
Atul

Comment: why do you have an infinite loop? this may cause locking happen so fast that select statement be block

Comment: `READ COMMITTED` does not hold shared lock after statement finished.

Answer (score 0):

select statement will not block inserts

Same way,selects will not block updates (unless you are in serializable isolation level).In other isolation levels ,select will take shared lock on row only **till duration of  read**,but not till end of transaction.

Remember Isolation levels only is for select statements to tell SQL on how long a lock is taken while selecting data or should I even take a lock.DDL statements will always take exclusive locks in heirarchial order on data it modifies

Comment: I think select with shared lock can block update as well as insert as both require exclusive lock. here is the reference for the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608780/understanding-sql-server-locks-on-select-queries