# Sql server simple locking example

Tags: sql, sql-server, express, locking, sql-server-2014

I thought I understood the locking mechanism from SQL, but it seems that I do not. I do know that you can have shared and exclusive locks and that 2 shared locks can be applied at the same data at the same time. But can someone explain me why query 1 doesn't block query 2. I expect that the serializable keyword will give me a exclusive lock instead of a shared lock. To get concrete:

I created a user table:

- id [int]
- name [nvarchar50)

Than I opened sql management studio connected to that database with user1 and execute the following query:

```
BEGIN TRAN
  select * from [user] WITH(SERIALIZABLE, TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

> I keep the transaction open on purpose.

Than I open a second sql mangement studio connect to the same database with user2 and execute the same query. I Expected that 2nd query keeps running, since query 1 is remaining a lock on the table, but it doesnt. The 2nd query is executed directly. Why is this? Are my lock hints ignored?

Comment: This thread has your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608780/understanding-sql-server-locks-on-select-queries

Comment: @YogeshSharma: Added the tags.

Comment: @Rigerta: Well not really, I understand the answer in that thread fully and isn't new to me. My point is that I force a exclusive lock with my read query but it seems that it is not working.

Comment: You can check your query's locks by querying `sys.dm_tran_locks` while you are running the select. You will only be getting a `S` (shared) lock, not an exclusive one. To force it to use an IX lock you will need to use the following: `WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)`

Comment: @RigertaDemiri: Thanks! That was it. You are right, so I was passing the wrong hints as it seems? What does the serializeable hint do? I thought it will require a Exclusive lock until the current transaction is ended. p.s.: Mayby convert your comment into a answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Ah misunderstood serializeable is more about the duration of the lock instead of the locking type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding SQL Server LOCKS on SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608780/understanding-sql-server-locks-on-select-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is very well explained [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608780/understanding-sql-server-locks-on-select-queries) that a `SELECT` statement cannot block another one, since both only acquire a `Shared (S)` lock on the resource, which means the row is available for reading. Read more [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/locking-sql-server/) on all lock types.

However, you were trying to force a select statement into acquiring an `Exclusive (X)` lock by using `WITH(SERIALIZABLE, TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` hints.

Those hints *"apply only to the table or view you are using it on and only for the duration of the transaction defined by the statement that they are used in"*. This is stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table).

The `SERIALIZABLE` hint is making shared locks more restrictive by holding them until a transaction is completed, instead of releasing the lock as soon as the data is no longer needed. But keep in mind, it is still a **shared lock**.

In order to force an exclusive lock you could do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)

SELECT resource_type, request_mode, resource_description
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE resource_type <> 'DATABASE'
```

The second query will give you information on all acquired locks from this statement.
I got the following results, by selecting on some table:

[image]

Note that we got an `Intent shared (IX)` lock on the `PAGE` and on the `OBJECT` itself, which is the table we are selecting from and an `Exclusive (X)` lock on every key.

Answer (score 1):

1. `SERIALIZABLE = HOLDLOCK` Makes shared locks
2. `TABLOCK` Specifies that the acquired lock is applied at the table level.

`(SERIALIZABLE, TABLOCK)` =  Shared (S) lock on Table

If need Exclusive (X) lock use on
`TABLOCKX` or  `(TABLOCK,UPDLOCK)`  or `(TABLOCK,XLOCK)`