# Transaction with DTC not locking its reads

Tags: c#, sql-server, isolation-level, msdtc, idempotent

This is what I am trying to do and it doesn't lock the transaction reads

```
using( transaction = TransactionScope()) //Default ReadCommitted Isoloation
{
    read transactionid  (stored procedure without nolock)

    if transactionid ispending do transaction else return
    mark transactionid is completed
    transaction.finish()
}
```

But it allows simultaneous calls to succeed doing transaction. Shouldn't this only succeed if it's using a `nolock`?

It seems to be working fine with (**updlock**) and (**rowlock**)

Would using `updlock` in a stored procedure lead to other issues like deadlock? (seems okay)

I would like to lock only that particular row and not the table.

Another option is `IsolationLevel` but not sure which one is granular enough for this?

Also I don't want to lock other reads inside this transactions which may occur.

Only want to ensure that once `transactionwrapper` created and when transactionid read happens every other simultaneous reads will wait until this transactionid is read is completed in the scope its running and therefore will quit

Comment: If you are asking why two `select`s don't block each other, then it's because they are [not supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610346/11683).

Comment: Thanks for this, but combine this with Transaction in the code =>  wouldnt the transactionwrappers ReadCommitted isolation level ensure that any other transaction with this dataset will get the latest data (i.e the first one to enter transaction with this data will be committed before other can read)?

Comment: Please click the link that explains it. It lacks a further link to the [lock compatibility matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#lock_compatibility), so also consult that.