When updating many rows in a column of a SQL table, how can I skip rows which are locked, or that are taking too long to update
The application is coded in .NET using ASP.NET webforms. I am trying to change the Priority code of several hundred order numbers.
The new code to be assigned is what the user selects in the Drop down list next to the order number in the GridView.
Here is my SQL update statement which executes when the user clicks the update button:
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DropDownList PTY_CHANGE = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("PTY_CHANGE");
    
    cnn3.Open();
                    
    query = @"
BEGIN TRAN T1
    UPDATE DATAORDERS
    SET DATAORDERS.PRIORITYCODE =@PTYCODE
    WHERE DATAORDERS.ORDERNO  =@ORDERNO
COMMIT TRAN T1";
    
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn3);
     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PTYCODE ", PTY_CHANGE.SelectedItem.Value);     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderno", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
     
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;       
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
       
    cnn3.Close();
}

The problem that I'm encountering is that some of the orders are locked (most likely someone else in the company is working on that order in a different module), so the code just stalls.
I'd like to skip that order and then try updating the next order number in the list.
Thank you for your help.

Look into READPAST and UPDLOCK table hints

this might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770402/sql-2008-nolock-vs-readpast-considerations-for-reporting-accuracy

What should "someone else is working on it" mean? Are you sure you simply want to skip intended updates? This sounds quite risky. How many operations are possible? How many and which accesses take place and how are they priorized? Often, people tend to simply use READPAST (as mentioned in the answer). But that might be absolutely incorrect because it simply could prevent necessary updates from being executed. Hard to say what would be best here without further information.

Basically, the order is open in a specific module of the ERP, such a shipping or one of the Production modules. The way the ERP is designed when an order is open/active in a Module, there is lock on it from the Database side and it cannot be modified. Generally I think this is good. The column I am trying to update (PriotiyCode) is not essential to 98% of the ERP Modules. So if an order is open in one of these modules it can be skipped.

Worth nothing that SQL Server 2007 reached e d of life over 5 years ago; you urgently need to upgrade the version you are using. Using such an outdated, and insecure, version is a concern for you, your colleagues and your clients.

Not to mention: Suggested reading: AddWithValue() is evil.

@kvj I've worked on systems that use locks like this, but never any that actually held them at the SQL level. It was always an application level construct. It's NUTS to hold an SQL lock while waiting on a user window like this. I image it must be holding open a data reader with an xlock hint or similar, and that's an insane way to handle this.

READPAST Specifies that the Database Engine not read rows that are locked by other transactions.
BEGIN TRAN T1
  UPDATE DATAORDERS WITH (READPAST)
  SET DATAORDERS.PRIORITYCODE =@PTYCODE WHERE DATAORDERS.ORDERNO =@ORDERNO
COMMIT TRAN T1


Wow thanks! This looks great. I'm going to try this solution and hopefully this should fix the problem. Thank you.

As already mentioned, this could easily cause unintended behaviour. Might be simple, but often simple = lazy = incorrect. Be very careful when using such functionality. How do you know you can really skip affected rows and how do you know why they are affected?

I think you raise a good point, and I will discuss this with the Application users. One of the consequences of this solution is certain orders will not be updated.  Basically, then the user will need to perform the Search query again in the Application (ie. Show all orders with Priority C,D, etc) and then the Gridview result will display the orders that were not updated/ie the orders which had locks on them.

Yes, that is what I meant. The user might wonder why their change doesn't have the expected affect (especially if they don't get a meaningful message what happened) and try again. And again. And might lock further rows that prevent other users from doing their operations. This READPAST can be a good solution, but it can also make things even worse. Depends on your use case.

Any ideas, how I can capture the orders, that encountered the READPAST Statement and were determined to have a lock. I'd just like to know how I can Identify these orders and then I would store them in a DataTable and display them in a Label, once the Query execution is completed.

Just run a query to capture the candidate records then compare after the attempted update of the candidates.

The fact we're already up to cnn3 is a big hint here.
When I see numbered connection objects like this, its a big red flag you've made one of two mistakes:

You're trying to keep a long-lived connection and re-use it in your app. You then end up with numbered connections in situations where you know something else is already using your "regular" connection.
This is a mistake because ADO.NET already does connection pooling for you, and re-using your own connection interferes with this in bad ways. Connection objects should be short-lived, and not usually re-used at all.

You're doing multiple operations on the client that should happen as part of a single large batch on the server... usually combined into the same statement.


It's a good bet #2 is a big part of what's causing your issue here. Programmers normally want less complexity, but this is a situation where you should write fewer, larger, more-complicated SQL statements. This will in turn greatly simplify your client code. The complexity is then moved into the database in a safe way. This helps avoid deadlocks.

Additionally, you should know that ADO.Net sessions give you an implicit transaction. That is, you don't need to wrap your sql strings with BEGIN TRANSACTION + COMMIT. You only need those commands in ADO.NET if you're using them as part of something more complicated, where the transaction may span multiple statements on the same connection, you have a situation where you may also need to ROLLBACK, or you've put multiple statements into the same sql string and you want an atomic commit partway through.

Finally, it's nuts to close and re-open the connection in a tight loop like this. You can open the connection once before the loop (which, as per #1 above should be a short-lived object), and close it once at the end (and a ideally let a using block or directive do that for us).
I should also talk about AddWithValue(), but I'll leave that for the updated code:
string query = @"
UPDATE DATAORDERS
SET DATAORDERS.PRIORITYCODE =@PTYCODE
WHERE DATAORDERS.ORDERNO  =@ORDERNO";

using var cnn3 = new SqlConnection("connection string here");
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn3);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;  

// Use actual database types and lengths here!
// Do NOT let ADO.NET infer parameter types, because sometimes it gets it wrong,
//  and when it does the performance loss can be AWFUL!
var pty = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PTYCODE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
var orderNum = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ORDERNO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);

cnn3.Open();
foreach (var row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    DropDownList PTY_CHANGE = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("PTY_CHANGE");
    pty.Value = PTY_CHANGE.SelectedItem.Value;
    orderNum.Value =  row.Cells[0].Text;          
        
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // why use ExecuteReader() for a statement that doesn't return any data?
}
// don't need to call cnn3.Close() The using directive takes care of it for us.

Even better if you refactor this to send up a single table-value parameter and do it all in ONE TRIP to the database.
Again: this won't fix your problem, because it's in other code. And any suggestions for manipulating locks are patching over it a way that could set you up for tainted data. Your true solution will lie elsewhere in the application.
But this is a significant improvement over what you're doing.
Of course, I'm also making some assumptions about reasonable isolation levels set at the database or connection level.

But if you really want to just skip past these, my recommendation is to set a very short timeout... say, 3 seconds. That's more than enough time for a single-row change, which would commonly happen in a matter of milliseconds. Then you can have a try/catch inside the loop to handle the timeout exception. Of course, that leaves you open to timeout issues from other sources, but this is your only indication. There's no other signal from the database whether your waiting on a lock, or authentication, or just general network slowness.

I appreciate the time and effort you've spent to come up with this answer and all the other details. Two things I've taken from here, Certainly I'll be changing the .AddWithValue Statements.  It makes more sense that way. Also, opening the connection before the For Loop seems reasonable, but initially I was weary about that since basically the connection could stay open for an unknown amount of time, depending on how long it takes for the command to executes.

This is why I preferred to open and close it within the for loop, since best case scenario the connection only stays open for a few seconds a time

I agree about cnn3 but that was just lazy code writing on my part, however the preceding SQL connections were closed before cnn3 was opened, as I definitely wouldn't open a new SQL connection while an existing one stays open. I'm thinking it's probably just best to reduce the Query timeout time from 3 minutes to about 30 seconds. It's just that the at some instances the Application will most likely timeout and if I don't have the correction exception handling in the code, i'll be getting lots of angry emails from users haha.
