# What actually happens when locks are acquired in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In other words, what are the steps to acquire locks ? Also, when 'WITH(Nolock)' hint is added to a query/'Read Uncommitted' Isolation level is used, does this avoid all or some of the overheads associated with acquiring locks ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effect of NOLOCK hint in SELECT statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210171/effect-of-nolock-hint-in-select-statements)

Comment: Take a look here https://www.brentozar.com/sql/locking-and-blocking-in-sql-server/ Lots of useful information.

Comment: `NOLOCK` means *gimme dirty data*, not *avoid locks*. Overheads aren't caused by locks, they are caused by unoptimized statements or using accessing data you don't need. You can use snapshot isolation to avoid locking but that has a *higher* IO overhead.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Do you have a statement that waits for too long? Are you trying to read and write in a long running transaction (which is 999.99% a bug)? Are you trying to use an ORM to read and update objects inside a single transaction (another serious bug)?

Comment: Other possibilities are bulk updates, typically caused by improperly denormalized data. Using loops or cursors instead of a single UPDATE or INSERT statement. Lazily loading dependent objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is too big for a specific answer, but in a nutshell SQL Server will employ various types of locks depending on request being made of it.  A select might acquire one type of lock and an update will acquire another.

This link has a good 101 on the subject.  [SQL Server locking Basics](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server)

And this one too

[Another good locking read](http://blogs.extremeexperts.com/2012/11/15/sql-server-locking-basics/)