# Temp Variable Assignment WITH (NOLOCK)

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, nolock

Is there a speed benefit to using WITH (NOLOCK) in temporary variable assignment. Meaning:

This

```
DECLARE @oldestPerson INT = (SELECT TOP 1 Age FROM tbl_Persons)
```

Verses

```
DECLARE @oldestPerson INT = (SELECT TOP 1 Age FROM tbl_Persons WITH (NOLOCK))
```

given that NOLOCK and READUNCOMMITTED are not allowed for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql. Does temporary variable assignment qualify under this rule as an INSERT?

Comment: [Effect of NOLOCK hint in SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210171/effect-of-nolock-hint-in-select-statements) - FYI without an ORDER BY there is no guarantee what row you will get.

Comment: Why do you want to use `NOLOCK` in the first place?

Comment: There is no effect unless the table is locked